# Как ускорить работу кода "статистика запросов" (Java)

Tags: java

Собственно говоря само задание:
есть файл input.txt который содержит запросы, частоту этих запросов и список начала запросов пользователей.

формат следующий:

n

запрос (пробел) частота

....

m

начало запроса

....

n < 10^5

m < 15000

запрос и начало запроса - строка не длиннее 15

частота запроса < 10^6

Нужно реализовать функцию auto-complete в поисковой системе. Когда пользователь набирает несколько первых букв запроса, система должна предложить ему самые популярные запросы, начинающиеся на эти буквы.

файл output.txt должен содержать самые популярные, (не более 10, отсортированные убыванию частоты) варианты запросов.

Ограничения: программа должна работать не более 2 сек. и выделять не более 100 Мб оперативной памяти.

Код рабочий, но на больших тестах не укладываюсь в лимит времени, подскажите что можно сделать.

Я только начал изучать Java так что сильно не пинайте если что....
собственно сам код:

```
public class TaskImpl {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long a=System.currentTimeMillis();

    SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> outMap = new TreeMap<>();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/input.txt"));
    String[] str = new String [2];
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    //Читаем тексты запросов и их частоту в Map
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        str = reader.readLine().split(" ");
        map.put(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]));
    }


    int m = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Читаем в List массив начала запросов
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        list.add(reader.readLine());
    }


    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("resources/output.txt"));

    //Для каждой итерации листа 
    for (String req : list) {

        //ищем из Map все что совпадает с началом запроса
        outMap = map.subMap(req, req + "\u0450");

        //сортируем полученный Map по значению (имеено этот процесс длится самое долгое время)
        outMap = sortByValue(outMap);


        //пишем первые 10 значений в выходной файл
        int count = 0;
        for (Map.Entry iter : outMap.entrySet()) {
            count++;
            if (count > 10) break;
            bufferedWriter.write((String)iter.getKey()+"\n");
        }
        bufferedWriter.write("\n");
    }

    bufferedWriter.close();

    long b=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total time, ms "+(b-a));
    System.out.println("memory "+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
            - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1024/1024 + " mb");
  }

public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map)
{
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2)
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    } );

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
    {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

На малых выборках работает быстро, но с максимальными значениями в лимит не укладываюсь 8-12 сек... Буду признателен за подсказки.

Заранее спасибо.

Вроде бы получилось
код немного видоизменился, но принципиальных отличий нет:
использовал кэш для повторяющихся подстрок запросов, изменил циклы и инициализации. Во временные ограничения уложился.

Вот код, может кому понадобится:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> cache = new HashMap<>();
String filename = args.length == 0 ? "resources/input_example.txt" : args[0];
String fileOutput = args.length == 0 ? "resources/output.txt" : args[1];

try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {

  //читаем количество запросов n
  int n = 0;

    n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String str[] = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    int freq = 0;
    try {
      freq = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.err.println("Ошибочный формат файла input.txt: неверный формат запроса. Ошибка в " + (i+2) + "-ой строке");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    if (freq < 1 || freq > 1e6) System.err.println("Предупреждение : Ошибочный формат файла input.txt. Неверно указана частота запроса. Ошибка в " + (i+2) + "-ой строке");
    map.put(str[0], freq);
  }

  try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOutput))) {

    //Читаем количество строк начала запросов пользователей m
    int m = 0;
    try {
      m = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

      if (m < 1 || m > 15000) {
        System.err.println("Ошибочный формат файла input.txt: количество префиксов должно быть в промежутке от 1 и до 15000");
        System.exit(1);
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.err.println("Ошибочный формат файла input.txt: ошибочно указано количество префиксов.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    int count;

    //Цикл по всем строкам
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      //Читаем
      String input = null;
      try {
        input = reader.readLine();
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Ошибочный формат файла input.txt: количество префиксов не соответствует заданному.");
        System.exit(1);
      }

       if (!cache.containsKey(input)) {
        List<String> requests = new ArrayList<>();


        Map<String, Integer> outMap = map.subMap(input, input + "{");

        outMap = sortByValue(outMap);

        count = 0;

        for (Map.Entry iter : outMap.entrySet()) {
          count++;
          if (count > 10) break;
          requests.add(iter.getKey().toString());
        }

        cache.put(input, requests);
      }

      for (String s : cache.get(input)) {
        bufferedWriter.write(s);
        bufferedWriter.write("\n");
      }
      bufferedWriter.write("\n");
    }
  }
}

System.out.println("Общее время: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start + ", мс"));
System.out.println("Память: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
        - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024 + " Мб");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что решение "в лоб" не уложится по времени. На то задачка и рассчитана.

От вас ожидают, что вы построите по исходным данным [префиксное дерево (trie)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) на котором запросы вида "верни все строки, начинающиеся как данная" отрабатывают очень быстро.

В стандартную библиотеку trie не входит (тогда бы и задача сводилась к использованию готового класса), но нет никаких сложностей, чтобы написать неоптимизированную реализацию самостоятельно (или найти на гитхабе).

Comment: я замерял время выполнения, если убрать сортировку по значению: outMap = sortByValue(outMap), время приемлемое. Не уверен, что префиксное дерево - выход из ситуации, т.к. сортировка осуществляется по значению, а не по ключу. Может сортировку в отдельные потоки помещать? Или это не выход?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил алгоритм частичной сортировки (исходя из того, что узкое горлышко это именно сортировка). То есть алгоритм, который выводит топ-15 позиций (остальные все равно неинтересны).

Посмотрите на [такой алгоритм](https://gist.github.com/mesuvash/4095565) - уверен его можно приспособить к вашей задаче.

Comment: Возможно у меня сам алгоритм работы программы неверен.. Может "зайти с другой стороны"?